# Jenkins pipeline access denied for modification or saving the changes

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am able to access my Jenkins and make changes to pipelines when I connected to home network without VPN. When I connect to my office network or office VPN I am able to access and manage Jenkins, But not able to make changes or save configuration of my Jenkins pipelines. I am getting below access denied message, Can anyone help me how to resolve this issue.

Your access is

denied

Access denied due to firewall policy violation

Your issue ID for support is: 65e9b94e-b-19bbb37f-c0000000

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4Hj9.png)

I have looked into my firewall and added all the necessary IP addresses in the network, even if it is related to firewall issue I shouldn't be able to access Jenkins and manage, But I am facing access denied issue only when I try to make changes or configuration to pipelines.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.